# Herb Sutter Atomic Weapons "Why Standalone Fences are Suboptimal"

Tags: c++, multithreading

Towards the end of his [talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) about memory barriers (fences), he gave the following example (**Note**: `global` is *not* of atomic type):

```
// thread 1                                     // thread 2
widget *temp = new widget();
global = temp;
                                                global->do_something();
                                                global->do_something_else();
```

Later he said we should have full fences as the follows:

```
   // thread 1                                     // thread 2
   widget *temp = new widget();
XX mb();   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   global = temp;
                                                   temp2 = global;
                                                XX mb(); XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
                                                   temp2->do_something();
                                                   temp2 = global;
                                                XX mb(); XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                   temp2->do_something_else();
```

I wonder why in thread 1 you need a barrier? `global` depends on `temp` and compiler wouldn't move `global = temp;` above the construction of `temp` anyway. One reason I can think of that needs the memory barrier is that the statement `global=temp;` somehow can be done in the middle of the construction of `new widget()` and thread 2 then would see a partially constructed `global`. Is that possible that assignment to `global` be scheduled in the middle of constructing new `widget`? Or the memory barrier is due to some other reasons?

Also in thread 2, don't you need another barrier after `temp2->do_something();`? As in the currently transformed form, the following statements can still be reordered during execution:

```
                                                   temp2 = global;
                                                XX mb(); XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

                                                   temp2 = global;
                                                   temp2->do_something();

                                                XX mb(); XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                   temp2->do_something_else();
```

And this is not what you intended since now you only invoke member functions on one `temp2` instead of reading a new value from `global` before executing `do_something_else()`.

If no such reordering is possible in thread 2, then why do we need the barriers in the first place in thread 2 if `temp2->do_something();` can't be reordered before `temp2 = global;`.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why in thread 1 you need a barrier? global depends on temp
>   and compiler wouldn't move global = temp; above the construction of
>   temp anyway.

It has to do with initialization of the inner members of `temp`. Due to CPU caching and reordering, without memory barrier here `global` might have the address of new `temp`, but memory pointed to by `temp` might appear uninitialized.

As for the second question, obviosuly

```
temp2->do_something();
temp2 = global;
```

can not be reordered as

```
temp2 = global;
temp2->do_something();
```

as it will do something on the very different object!

Comment: Ok. As I suspected. What about question on thread 2? Do you need another barrier after `temp2->do_something();`?

Comment: @Rich, answered that as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment on thread 2. Why can't they be reordered? Does compiler and hardware honor the order of write after read operations here? and what different objects are involved?

Comment: @Rich, and I am not sure what you do not understand. `temp2` is a pointer to a specific object. When you ask compiler first to do something with this object, and than replace the pointer with something else, compiler can't instead first replace the pointer with something else, and than do something with the new object!

Comment: @Rich, to make modifications done through 'do_something` visible to other threads (after all, they were done in the global object).

Comment: Without the barrier, other threads wouldn't see the modifications done through `do_something`?

Comment: @Rich, they might not see it, right. (they also need a barrier on their side, of course).

Comment: I thought thread 2 only require an **Acquire** semantics. To my understanding, to publish changes needs **release** semantics.If we only need acquire semantics on the `global`, I don't still understand why we need a full fence here. Basically, what acquire semantics can be broken due to reordering without the barriers?

Comment: @Rich, I do not understand your question.

Comment: Unless `do_something()` and `do_something_else()` operations change the variable `global` while we read (**acquire** semantics) `global` (twice in original code), we don't need barriers, right? and it seems absurd, since `do_something()` is a member function, to have member functions modify the object (even though it is global variable) they are called on before the object is fully read. So there wouldn't be a race without the barriers, right?

Comment: you need an aquire barrier in the beginning, and release barrier in the end. I think, a general barrier is used here in both places for simplicity.